# Getting percent sign into an URL in a footnote

Tags: footnotes, urls

I'm using the `url` package. Now, I have some some url with a percent sign in it and want to place it in a footnote. When I let the `%` where it is, I get a comment, and the whole thing fails to compile because of some unmatched brackets. When it's at the end of a line, it doesn't show up at all in the result. When I write `\%` instead, this gets literally into the output—but I want the url to be displayed correctly.

What could I do?

Comment: What are you using to create URLs? `\url{foo%.com}` works fine for me with the `url` package

Comment: pdfLaTeX, on miktex

Comment: @phg I meant, are you using the `url` package (`\usepackage{url}` in your preamble) or some other package that defines a `\url{}` command?

Comment: Yeah, I was using \usepackage{url}, but I just saw I screwed it up somewhere else, because I was using it inside a footnote and then the error was kept somehow. Im sorry, problem solved... but thanks for really fast help.

Comment: @Seamus: Could you post this as an answer.

Comment: Or should this be simply closed?

Comment: @Caramdir post _what_ as an answer? I didn't answer anything! I think we could close this...

Comment: @Seamus: That it should “just work”. But Martin has a better answer already. So just ignore me :)

Comment: You can also use some of online websites that provide a new short form of link address to your original link address, they usually don't include % sign etc, for example bitly.com or other similar ones, then use the new link address. But the new form may be not informative since it doesn't show the mother domain, for example the link maybe a page in the website of a university, so the original link gives some extra information other than just a link to click on.

Answer (score 41):

For URLs in footnotes or inside other macro arguments use `\urldef` to define it first as a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\urldef\myurl\url{foo%.com}
\begin{document}
text\footnote{WWW: \myurl}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for long URLs - https://svn.ggy.bris.ac.uk/websvn/listing.php?repname=genie&path=%2Fbranches%2Fgreg-s_branch%2F&rev=6324 will print correctly in the document, but the link doesn't work as it's only half complete.

Comment: @user8875 This method does work for long url's too, just make sure you don't break it in the definition.  To get an active link, load the `hyperref` package.

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way is to simply escape it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    text\footnote{%
        \href{http://example.com/name\%27s-page}{http://example.com/name's-page}%
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I found that adding a "\" in front of the "%" in the URL produces a working URL.

Comment: But then the backslash appears in the URL, you don't want that.

Comment: It is actually not necessary to escape percent signs in `\href{}{}` using the hyperref package. The percent sign might confuse text highlighting in your text editor though (for example Overleaf).

Comment: You also have to escape the `#` and `&` signs with a backslash in urls.

Comment: @erik Considering @Paul Rougieux Do you have to escape `#` and `&`, or don't you? I mean you don't have to escape `%`...

Comment: Best answer by far.

Comment: I did need to escape it and it did not result in it appearing in the URL. This is actually the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: Other than the precent sign needing escaping `% -> \%` , the  `#` and `&` signs wont show error in tex file but will give error after compiling (wont impact the generated file though).. to even remove the compilation error, we need to escape `# -> \#` and `& -> \&`