# URL containing a question mark with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, urls

I have a Bugzilla URL, that looks like this:

```
http://host/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1234]
```

And I would like to include it using `\href`:

```
\href{http://host/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1234}{issue \#1234}
```

Unfortunately, the above "helpfully" translates the question mark to `%3F`, i.e. a *quoted* question mark.  I want an actual question mark there.

[Editing to add failing code -- thanks Thorsten and Marco].  Here is an MWE:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{http://host/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1234}{issue \#1234}
\end{document}
```

Clicking on the link takes me to `http://host/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi%3Fid=1234`; but I would like to go to `http://host/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1234`.

What should I do?

Comment: What's your code? I don't see any problem there.

Comment: Which version of `hyperref` do you use?

Comment: @Marco: Either 6.71 (the RCS comment in `hyperref.sty`) or 6.74 (the `\ProvidesPackage` there).

Comment: Ok. In my distribution TexLive 2011 I have the version `2011/04/17 v6.82g`. Maybe an update is helpfully.

Comment: @Marco: Nope.  Updated to `2011/04/17 v6.82g` from CTAN, above MWE gives the same results.  Note that the difference might show up only upon clicking the link.

Comment: Would some [`\urldef`-fu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/getting-percent-sign-into-an-url-in-a-footnote/12233#12233) help?

Comment: I have no problems with the link. I tested with okular and abobe. Have anybody else some problems?

Comment: I confirm no problem.

Comment: It turns out to be a viewer problem.  I am using evince 0.6.0, which opens the links incorrectly.  Using e.g. Adobe Reader 9.4 works perfectly.

Comment: @ariels: on that basis I'm closing 'too localized' - this is not actually a TeX issue at all.