# Displaying % (percent) symbol in footnotes using \url

Tags: footnotes, urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting percent sign into an URL in a footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/getting-percent-sign-into-an-url-in-a-footnote)

In reference to this question: [Getting percent sign into an URL in a footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/getting-percent-sign-into-an-url-in-a-footnote)

I'm using the `url` package and am still having trouble getting the `%` symbol to display right in footnotes. If I enter the URL address as is, I get error messages, but if I insert backslashes (replacing `%` with `\%`) the backslashes show up in the text. Any ideas on how to get the percent symbol to display properly?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've done/attempted in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. When I compile the MWE in your linked post, the `%` shows up as expected.

Comment: Thanks. So I have:

\footnote{\url{http://web.mac.com\%3A5\%3A11.pdf}.}

And the backslashes show up in the text. If I don't put them in, it won't even compile because everything after the first % gets treated as comment text.

Comment: Note that the linked example uses `\urldef\myurl\url{web.mac.com\%3A5\%3A11.pdf}` and then `\footnote{\myurl}` and not the nested `\footnote{\url{...}}` notation.

Comment: OK, that works. I didn't think it would compile with that definition of \myurl, since part of it shows up as comment text in my editor. But it does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only safe way to use URLs containing special characters such as `%` in footnotes is via `\urldef`:

```
\urldef{\webmaccom}\url{web.mac.com%3A5%3A11.pdf} % in the preamble

\footnote{\webmaccom} % in the document
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to vote these answers up but now that I've registered I'm not getting "credit" for this question. Is there a way to tell the system that I asked this question? (I'm only able to write this comment because I registered using another browser.)

Comment: The question will be closed as duplicate; you should register on the site, in order to be able to upvote and comment. Then a moderator can merge your registered account with the unregistered one.

Comment: OK. How do I get a moderator to merge my accounts?

Comment: I will flag your question to make them aware.

Answer (score 6):

Every editor is different. For example, even in this answer, the formatting may seem incorrect:

```
\urldef\myurl\url{web.mac.com%3A5%3A11.pdf}
```

But, the compiler will in interpret this correctly. Since URLs typically have strange (or special) characters in them, people are also inclined to use `\verb|web.mac.com%3A5%3A11.pdf|`. However, verbatim content is known to be problematic when passed as an argument. As such, you need to resort to using packages like [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) for appropriate passing.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, verbatim seemed dangerous. And again, it was surprising that something that showed up as commentary in my front-matter still compiled.

Comment: @twofeet: As mentioned, the editor has no indication of the compiled output, which is dependent on category codes.