# Defining a command where the argument could contain percent signs

Tags: macros, urls

This minimal example won't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{#1}
\begin{document}
\mycommand{\url{http://www.example.org/index.php?a=Hello%20World.}}
\end{document}
```

The reason is the percent sign inside the URL. Note that a percent sign occurs often in URLs and that the `\url` command usually handles it correctly. How do I fix this?

Comment: I found duplicates, but I think I lack the reputation to link them: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42413/displaying-percent-symbol-in-footnotes-using-url?lq=1 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/getting-percent-sign-into-an-url-in-a-footnote?rq=1

The only solution is a workaround but if there is no better solution this can be closed.

Comment: Do you need the `\url` at all? Or are you looking for a command that has a verbatim argument which allows `%` then?  Something like `\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{v}{#1}` (use `xparse` package for this!)

Comment: Yes, I need the `\url`. I want it to be clickable in the PDF.