# Problem while using \href the "%" sign creates problem

Tags: urls

I am using

`\href{http://abcd/x/y%z/abcd.html}`

but `%` creates problem. It is getting commented after `%` but I have `%` in my address, and `\%` did not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does this question and the associated answers help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12230/31058 ?

Comment: use `\href{http://abcd/x/y\%z/abcd.html}`

Comment: Erh, `\href` takes two arguments, perhaps you are confusing it with `\url`? Both `\href{...}{...}` and `\url{...}` handles `%` without problems in the first argument.

Answer (score 4):

@Daleif is right.

`href` takes two arguments, and is usually used for things like a picture that you want to make "clickable" and guide you to a webpage e.g.:

```
\href{http://www.thefoowebapge.com}{\includegraphics{foopicture.jpeg}}
```

Or if you want to set up a text for it to guide you to a different address:

```
\href{http://wwww.thefoowebpage.com}{In our website}
```

On the other hand, `url` can be used for what you are looking for, which is convert an address into a clickable text without any problems e.g.:

```
\url{http://abcd/x/y%z/abcd.html}
```

You shouldn't have any problems while using the `url` package, regardless of using `%`