# \url{} links with percent (%) signs and overfull hbox error

Tags: line-breaking, urls, warnings

I have looked at the first comment to [this question on % in urls](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/getting-percent-sign-into-an-url-in-a-footnote) and found that I didn't need to type `\` ahead of each `%`. However, in WinEdt 7.1, everything from the first `%` in the first URL is now greyed out and I do not know if this is why I am getting an error with the `overfull \hbox` when I compile to PDF.

The problem in LaTeX is

```
proposal P293 (see \url{http://www.foodstandards.govt.nz/code/proposals/documents/Reanalysis%20of%20Nutriti.pdf} and \url{http://www.foodstandards.govt.nz/code/proposals/documents/P293_SD3.pdf} for the full analysis reports of the experiments).
```

The auto linebreak for the second URL should be after `/code` and not after `/proposals` as `/proposals` is going past the right hand margin in my document.

How can I force the linebreak to occur in the correct place in the second URL and still have the link work correctly?

The start of my report class is

```
\documentclass[11pt,PhD]{muthesis}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
        bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
        head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `hyperref` package to improve the behavior of the `\url` command. Use it with `hidelinks` option to view black links. If you don't use `\%` (using the `url` or `hyperref`packages) all that happens is that WinEdt means a comment but nothing wrong happens to the output document.

Add the `\sloppy` command to solve the problem with overfull boxes.

```
\documentclass[11pt,PhD]{muthesis}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
        bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
        head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \sloppy
    proposal P293 (see \url{http://www.foodstandards.govt.nz/code/proposals/documents/Reanalysis\%20of\%20Nutriti.pdf} and \url{http://www.foodstandards.govt.nz/code/proposals/documents/P293_SD3.pdf} for the full analysis reports of the experiments).
\end{document}
```

You can read what the [sloppy](http://www.tug.org/tutorials/latex2e/%245csloppy.html) command does.

Comment: The \sloppy command has stopped the behaviour in the paragraph. I tried to use the hyperref package as suggested but got the apparently common error `! Argument of \contentsline has an extra }.' and my dissertation no longer compiled. I haven't been able to locate the source of that problem in the .cls or elsewhere, so I have chosen not to use that extra package.

Comment: @Michelle If with the url package works well, then use it. I recommend hyperref only to have a hyperlink. However it is strange that this error occurs, there must be something in the document that causes it.

Comment: `\sloppy` affects the entire document.  it's better to use `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` around just the paragraph or section that contains the problematic url to limit its effect.

Comment: @barbarabeeton certainly is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would just reformulate the sentence;

```
\documentclass[11pt]{muthesis}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\noindent Proposal~P293 (where the documents for the full analysis reports of the experiments can be found at \url{http://www.foodstandards.govt.nz/code/proposals/documents/Reanalysis%20of%20Nutriti.pdf} and \url{http://www.foodstandards.govt.nz/code/proposals/documents/P293_SD3.pdf}).

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If this is not an option, use the `sloppypar` environment as mentioned by barbara beeton in a comment to [OSjerick's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144315/15874).