# File ended while scanning use of \Gscale@box@dd

Tags: tables, errors

I am getting this error for a while now, and I can't seem to fix it?!
Here is my code - my table won't even load because of this error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering % used for centering table
\caption{Parameter Estimates} % title of Table
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} % centered columns (4 columns)
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
Description & Parameter & Estimate(per day) & Source \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table %heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
\hline
Population of Andhra Pradesh, Tamil Nadu, Maharashtra, and Karnataka & N & 330,308,167 & CIA World Factbook \\ \hline
Ratio of above population in India population & Scale & 0.2671651242 & Calculated \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{INITIAL CONDITIONS (POPULATIONS)}} \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-susceptible & $X_{SS}(0)$ & 192,941,151 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-infected & $X_{ST}(0)$ & 132,478,723 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV+, TB-susceptible & $X_{HS}(0)$ & 2,422,951 & Calculated \\ \hline
Co-infected & $X_{HT}(0)$ & 1,817,998 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-treatment (1st stage) & $X_{S+T_T^{(1)}}(0)$ & 161,501 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-treatment (2nd stage) & $X_{S+T_T^{(2)}}(0)$ & 161,501 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-cured & $X_{S+T_T^{(3)}}(0)$ & 145,865 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV+, TB-cured & $X_{H+T_T^{(3)}}(0)$ & 117 & AIDSInfo Online Database \\ \hline
HIV+, TB-treatment (1st stage) & $X_{H+T_T^{(1)}}(0)$ & 7,953 & AIDSInfo Online Database \\ \hline
HIV+, TB-treatment (2nd stage) & $X_{H+T_T^{(2)}}(0)$ & 7,953 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, TB-treatment (1st stage) & $X_{H_T+T_T^{(1)}}(0)$ & 3,445 & UNAIDS Global report (2013) \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, TB-treatment (2nd stage) & $X_{H_T+T_T^{(2)}}(0)$ & 3,445 & Assumption \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, TB-cured & $X_{H_{T_1}}(0)$ & 3,032 & Worldbank data \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, no history of TB & $X_{H_{T_2}}(0)$ & 152,450 & WHO 2013 Global TB Report \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, paradoxical IRIS & $X_{IRIS}(0)$ & 82 & A5221 Stride Study \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{ADDITIONAL PARAMETERS}} \\ \hline
Recruitment/maturation rate & $\Lambda$ & 531,062 & CIA World Factbook \\ \hline
Natural death rate & $\mu$ & 3.9138943e-5 & \url{http://planningcommission.nic.in/data/datatable/0306/table%20226.pdf} \\ \hline
AIDS death rate & $\mu_H$ & 1.3698630e-3 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
TB death rate & $\mu_T$ & 5.4794521e-4 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
Paradoxical IRIS death rate & $\mu_{IRIS}$ & 4.8947959e-5 & Laureillard et al. (2011) \\ \hline
HIV sufficient contact rate & $\beta$ & 4.6575342e-4 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
TB sufficient contact rate & $\tau$ & 1.0958904e-2 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
HIV regular treatment rate & $\lambda_H$ & 1 & Varied \\ \hline
HIV early treatment rate & $\lambda_{H_1}$ & 0 & Varied \\ \hline
HIV late treatment rate & $\lambda_{H_2}$ & 1 & Varied \\ \hline
TB regular treatment rate & $\lambda_T$ & 1 & Varied \\ \hline
TB treatment stage transition rate (Stage 1 to Stage 2) & $\lambda_{T_1}$ & 1.6666667e-2 & Calculated \\ \hline
TB treatment stage transition rate (Stage 2 to Stage 3) & $\lambda_{T_2}$ & 8.3333333e-3 & Calculated \\ \hline
Rate of occurrence of paradoxical IRIS & $\gamma$ & 2.7528463e-4 & Bonnet et al. (2013) \\ \hline
Modification parameter & $\psi$ & 0.15 & Varied \\ \hline
Modification parameter & $\alpha$ & 0.075 & Estimated \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your `planningcommission` URL has a `%` which is the source of the problem. Escape it using `\%`.

Comment: the compilation works if you not use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}`

Comment: There are two unnecessary spaces before and after the table. Fix by commenting the line end: `\resizebox{%` and `\end{tabular}%`

Comment: There is hardly ever a good reason to scale a table like this `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{` (although if you must add a `%`there). It just introduces inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: @TimS.: That's because the argument (the entire `tabular`) is read by `\resizebox` without consideration of the `\url` command (it's just another macro). And, in doing so, there is a missing end-brace, causing the problem.

Comment: Another option is to use `\urldef` from the [`url` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url). See [Getting percent sign into an URL in a footnote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12230/5764).

Answer (score 3):

Scaling the table gives you little control over the font size. Here I've used `\footnotesize` which is really as small as you want to go. This bleeds into the margins but using subject knowledge you can probably abbreviate the first column headings and make it fit. Alternatively wrapping the existing headings to a narrower column but letting the table go to two pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
{
\centering % used for centering table
\vspace{-2cm}
\caption{Parameter Estimates} % title of Table
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\footnotesize

\hspace*{-2cm}\begin{tabular}{@{}|>{\raggedright}p{6cm}|l|l|l|} % centered columns (4 columns)
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
Description & Parameter & Estimate(per day) & Source \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table %heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
\hline
Population of Andhra Pradesh, Tamil Nadu, Maharashtra, and Karnataka & N & 330,308,167 & CIA World Factbook \\ \hline
Ratio of above population in India population & Scale & 0.2671651242 & Calculated \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{INITIAL CONDITIONS (POPULATIONS)}} \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-susceptible & $X_{SS}(0)$ & 192,941,151 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-infected & $X_{ST}(0)$ & 132,478,723 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV+, TB-susceptible & $X_{HS}(0)$ & 2,422,951 & Calculated \\ \hline
Co-infected & $X_{HT}(0)$ & 1,817,998 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-treatment (1st stage) & $X_{S+T_T^{(1)}}(0)$ & 161,501 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-treatment (2nd stage) & $X_{S+T_T^{(2)}}(0)$ & 161,501 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-cured & $X_{S+T_T^{(3)}}(0)$ & 145,865 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV+, TB-cured & $X_{H+T_T^{(3)}}(0)$ & 117 & AIDSInfo Online Database \\ \hline
HIV+, TB-treatment (1st stage) & $X_{H+T_T^{(1)}}(0)$ & 7,953 & AIDSInfo Online Database \\ \hline
HIV+, TB-treatment (2nd stage) & $X_{H+T_T^{(2)}}(0)$ & 7,953 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, TB-treatment (1st stage) & $X_{H_T+T_T^{(1)}}(0)$ & 3,445 & UNAIDS Global report (2013) \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, TB-treatment (2nd stage) & $X_{H_T+T_T^{(2)}}(0)$ & 3,445 & Assumption \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, TB-cured & $X_{H_{T_1}}(0)$ & 3,032 & Worldbank data \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, no history of TB & $X_{H_{T_2}}(0)$ & 152,450 & WHO 2013 Global TB Report \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, paradoxical IRIS & $X_{IRIS}(0)$ & 82 & A5221 Stride Study \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{ADDITIONAL PARAMETERS}} \\ \hline
Recruitment/maturation rate & $\Lambda$ & 531,062 & CIA World Factbook \\ \hline
Natural death rate & $\mu$ & 3.9138943e-5 & \textsuperscript{(1)} \\ \hline
AIDS death rate & $\mu_H$ & 1.3698630e-3 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
TB death rate & $\mu_T$ & 5.4794521e-4 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
Paradoxical IRIS death rate & $\mu_{IRIS}$ & 4.8947959e-5 & Laureillard et al. (2011) \\ \hline
HIV sufficient contact rate & $\beta$ & 4.6575342e-4 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
TB sufficient contact rate & $\tau$ & 1.0958904e-2 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
HIV regular treatment rate & $\lambda_H$ & 1 & Varied \\ \hline
HIV early treatment rate & $\lambda_{H_1}$ & 0 & Varied \\ \hline
HIV late treatment rate & $\lambda_{H_2}$ & 1 & Varied \\ \hline
TB regular treatment rate & $\lambda_T$ & 1 & Varied \\ \hline
TB treatment stage transition rate (Stage 1 to Stage 2) & $\lambda_{T_1}$ & 1.6666667e-2 & Calculated \\ \hline
TB treatment stage transition rate (Stage 2 to Stage 3) & $\lambda_{T_2}$ & 8.3333333e-3 & Calculated \\ \hline
Rate of occurrence of paradoxical IRIS & $\gamma$ & 2.7528463e-4 & Bonnet et al. (2013) \\ \hline
Modification parameter & $\psi$ & 0.15 & Varied \\ \hline
Modification parameter & $\alpha$ & 0.075 & Estimated \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\hspace*{-2cm}

}

\raggedright
\textsuperscript{(1)}
\url{http://planningcommission.nic.in/data/datatable/0306/table%20226.pdf}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A slight improvement to David Carlisle's version, with `threeparttable` and `makecell`:  table now fits ‘naturally’ into the margins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\usepackage[showframe,  no marginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{threeparttable, caption}
\captionsetup{font = footnotesize}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering % used for centering table
\caption{Parameter Estimates} % title of Table
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{threeparttable}
\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{@{}|>{\raggedright}l|l|l|l|} % centered columns (4 columns)
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
\thead{Description} &\thead{ Parameter} & \thead{Estimate\\(per day)} & \thead{Source} \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table %heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
\hline
\makecell{Population of Andhra Pradesh,Tamil Nadu,\\ Maharashtra, and Karnataka} & N & 330,308,167 & CIA World Factbook \\ \hline
\makecell{Ratio of above population\\ in India population} & Scale & 0.2671651242 & Calculated \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{INITIAL CONDITIONS (POPULATIONS)}} \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-susceptible & $X_{SS}(0)$ & 192,941,151 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-infected & $X_{ST}(0)$ & 132,478,723 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV+, TB-susceptible & $X_{HS}(0)$ & 2,422,951 & Calculated \\ \hline
Co-infected & $X_{HT}(0)$ & 1,817,998 & Calculated \\ \hline
\makecell{HIV-susceptible, TB-treatment \\(1st stage)} & $X_{S+T_T^{(1)}}(0)$ & 161,501 & Calculated \\ \hline
\makecell{HIV-susceptible, TB-treatment\\ (2nd stage)} & $X_{S+T_T^{(2)}}(0)$ & 161,501 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV-susceptible, TB-cured & $X_{S+T_T^{(3)}}(0)$ & 145,865 & Calculated \\ \hline
HIV+, TB-cured & $X_{H+T_T^{(3)}}(0)$ & 117 & AIDSInfo Online Database \\ \hline
\makecell{HIV+, TB-treatment \\(1st stage)} & $X_{H+T_T^{(1)}}(0)$ & 7,953 & AIDSInfo Online Database \\ \hline
\makecell{HIV+, TB-treatment\\ (2nd stage)} & $X_{H+T_T^{(2)}}(0)$ & 7,953 & Calculated \\ \hline
\makecell{HIV-treatment, TB-treatment \\ (1st stage)} & $X_{H_T+T_T^{(1)}}(0)$ & 3,445 & UNAIDS Global report (2013) \\ \hline
\makecell{HIV-treatment, TB-treatment\\ (2nd stage)} & $X_{H_T+T_T^{(2)}}(0)$ & 3,445 & Assumption \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, TB-cured & $X_{H_{T_1}}(0)$ & 3,032 & Worldbank data \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, no history of TB & $X_{H_{T_2}}(0)$ & 152,450 & WHO 2013 Global TB Report \\ \hline
HIV-treatment, paradoxical IRIS & $X_{IRIS}(0)$ & 82 & A5221 Stride Study \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{ADDITIONAL PARAMETERS}} \\ \hline
Recruitment/maturation rate & $\Lambda$ & 531,062 & CIA World Factbook \\ \hline
Natural death rate & $\mu$ & 3.9138943e-5 & \tnote{\textsuperscript{(1)}} \\ \hline
AIDS death rate & $\mu_H$ & 1.3698630e-3 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
TB death rate & $\mu_T$ & 5.4794521e-4 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
Paradoxical IRIS death rate & $\mu_{IRIS}$ & 4.8947959e-5 & Laureillard et al. (2011) \\ \hline
HIV sufficient contact rate & $\beta$ & 4.6575342e-4 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
TB sufficient contact rate & $\tau$ & 1.0958904e-2 & Long et al. (2008) \\ \hline
HIV regular treatment rate & $\lambda_H$ & 1 & Varied \\ \hline
HIV early treatment rate & $\lambda_{H_1}$ & 0 & Varied \\ \hline
HIV late treatment rate & $\lambda_{H_2}$ & 1 & Varied \\ \hline
TB regular treatment rate & $\lambda_T$ & 1 & Varied \\ \hline
\makecell{TB treatment stage transition rate\\ (Stage 1 to Stage 2)} & $\lambda_{T_1}$ & 1.6666667e-2 & Calculated \\ \hline
\makecell{TB treatment stage transition rate\\ (Stage 2 to Stage 3)} & $\lambda_{T_2}$ & 8.3333333e-3 & Calculated \\ \hline
Rate of occurrence of paradoxical IRIS & $\gamma$ & 2.7528463e-4 & Bonnet et al. (2013) \\ \hline
Modification parameter & $\psi$ & 0.15 & Varied \\ \hline
Modification parameter & $\alpha$ & 0.075 & Estimated \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1.5ex}
\begin{tablenotes}
  \item[\textsuperscript{(1)}]
\url{http://planningcommission.nic.in/data/datatable/0306/table%20226.pdf}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]