# % sign into URL in a footnote

Tags: footnotes, urls

Further to [Caramdir's (User 3872) 2011 question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12230); I have a similar MWE as in that question, hence:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\urldef{\eur50}\url{http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXSTOXX%3ASX5E&ei=Pj9GVMD5FuH4wgO_zoGIDg}
\begin{document}
text\footnote{\eur50}
\end{document}
```

This works for me with other url's in footnote. This example, however, seems too long and breaks by the `%` sign (shown here in grey).

Q:How can one load the long url with the `%` sign included as it is in the url? (so without `\` in front).

Comment: Hello, LION! :-)

Comment: Have you tried `\@`?

Comment: `\eur50` is an illegal name for the URL. I get several errors with the example, so the output is incorrect. Use `\eurl` or anything else provided it's letters only.

Comment: Could you please show which question do you refer to? I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: With egreg's suggested change your code works fine for me.

Comment: This is the Lion ;-) @egreg: this is correct, all compiles fine now; didn't know numbers are illegal in the reference. How to close question/ proceed now?

Comment: See http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=linmacnames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only letters are allowed in the commands defined with `\urldef`, so `\eur50` is illegal and, indeed, several errors appear when processing your example.

The problem is described in [this TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linmacnames); basically `\newcommand{\eur50}{...}` is not legal.

You *could* use digits by using a different strategy:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\namedurldef}[1]{%
  \expandafter\urldef\csname#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\namedurl}[1]{\csname#1\endcsname}


\namedurldef{eur50}\url{http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXSTOXX%3ASX5E&ei=Pj9GVMD5FuH4wgO_zoGIDg}
\begin{document}
text\footnote{\namedurl{eur50}}
\end{document}
```

[image]