# Add a special character in a latex url

Tags: symbols, footnotes, urls

I want to incorporate a link as a footnote to my latex text that contains a special character. That link is the following one:

> http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/cross-modal-emotions/

And the special character is `~`. I tried to incorporate the symbol in my text using the following: `$\~$` however, I got an error that I could not do that. I tried also to use `\sim` however, with that symbol I could not open the correct url. Any idea how can I add it in my text?

Comment: Use the `url` or `hyperref` package (`hyperref` loads `url` automatically, so no need to load both; `url` without `hyperref` will not link the URL) and write `\url{http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/cross-modal-emotions/}`.

Comment: Ah well, URLs in footnotes are much tricker if they contain special characters such as `~`. You can use `\urldef` if you also want additional text in the footnote (works with `url` or `hyperref`), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12230/35864, or something like `\makeatletter
  \newcommand\fnurl@[1]{\footnote{\url@{#1}}}
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\fnurl}{\hyper@normalise\fnurl@}
\makeatother` (works only with `hyperref`), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12855/35864.