# \URL --- \% appears as \% instead of %. But % itself works as a comment

Tags: url

In `\URL` --- `\%` appears as `\%` instead of `%`.  But `%` itself works as a comment...

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting percent sign into an URL in a footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/getting-percent-sign-into-an-url-in-a-footnote)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) . Did you try to insert just `%` as it is instead of `\%` in the url link source? (P.S. Ignore the editor masking, e.g. greying out, of the `%` and characters forward as this will not affect the compilation results). Also make sure you load the package `\usepackage{url}` in your preamble.

Comment: Are you talking about the url package alone or with hyperref?

Comment: @ Donald Arseneau url package alone.