# New command based on hyperref cannot handle special input characters

Tags: hyperref, input-encodings, renewcommand

My goal is to add a heavy underline to text that contains hyperlinks via the `hyperref`-package, such that, when printing out the file, one can see that there is a link hidded behind some words.

When adding a new command, `\myhref`, I found that the special German characters (ä,ö,ü,ß) contained in the `latin1`-options of `inputenc` are no longer working. In the normal `\href`, they are working, as they are contained in the `scrbook` document class, I believe.

```
\documentclass%
% [12pt,abstracton,titlepage,parskip=false, no, no,twoside=true,open=right]
{scrbook}


\usepackage[autooneside=false, headsepline, plainheadsepline, automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%%%%%                           Layout
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,soul} \setul{0.4ex}{0.3ex} \setulcolor{blue} \sethlcolor{yellow}

\newcommand{\myhref}[2]{%
\href{#1}{\ul{#2}}}

% \let\oldhref\href
% \renewcommand{\href}{%
%   \oldhref{#1}{\setulcolor{blue}\ul{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\myhref{www.google.com%}{Schär Schar. fließen. Önvestment Investment.}

\href{www.google.com%}{Schär Schar. fließen. Önvestment Investment.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Am I defining the new command wrongly?

As a comment pointed out, the solution was to use the package `soulutf8` instead of `soul` in order to make the unterline accept the characters. However, I now ran into the subsequent problem, that the new command `myhref` does not accept "%" in the URL, but the old command `href`does. I adjusted the MWE.

Comment: Use `soulutf8` package instead of `soul`.

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you!

Comment: ...That worked for links that do not contain a "%" sign in the url.
Now, ```\myhref{www.google.com}{Schär Schar}``` works, but ```\myhref{www.google.com/%}{Schär Schar}``` does not. It works for the normal href-command. What needs to be changed`?

Comment: you shouldn't edit your question like that. The problem with % is quite different to the problem with umlauts. Better ask a new question.

Comment: Either do some complicated things or just escape it. ([Getting percent sign into an URL in a footnote - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/getting-percent-sign-into-an-url-in-a-footnote))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solves both problems:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor,soulutf8}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myhref}{ v m }{\href{#1}{\ul{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\myhref{www.google.com/%}{Schär Schar. fließen. Önvestment Investment.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the link should start with https://, without the protocol hyperref will produce a file link instead of an URI.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer It works for me with valid link. For example `https://www.google.com/search?q=%25&hl=hu&source=hp&ei=BjHVY8q0C4-xrgSG_Zm4Bw&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAY9U_FgbE51fsYccKKtKggk3fKyiscDfP&ved=0ahUKEwjKz7LavOr8AhWPmIsKHYZ-BncQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%25&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANQAFgAYKwIaABwAHgAgAFZiAFZkgEBMZgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz`